# Different SEO for 2 pages with React, Firebase hosting + functions

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have a React app with react-router that has a landing page and 2 routes (that show separate things each on their own page), and I want both to have different meta tags for SEO. I deploy my app to Firebase Hosting. I read [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions) article from Google about the idea of rewriting and using cloud functions to generate some HTML to solve the SEO, but end up in an infinite loop.

Let's say I have example.com/1 and example.com/2. I want the users to be able to access example.com and navigate to 1 and 2, but the SEO to be different. I wrote a cloud function that would rewrite /1 to run :

```
  exports.myFunction = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  cors(req, res, () => {

      string = `
      <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html lang="en">
  
      <head>
          <meta charset="UTF-8">
          <title>Page1</title>
      </head>
  
      <body>
          //<script>window.location = "https://example.com/1"</script>
      </body>
  
      </html>
      `;

    res.send(string);
  });
});
```

I was thinking to do this window.location trick from [here](https://hackernoon.com/firebase-to-the-rescue-dynamic-routing-via-hosting-functions-integration-aef888ddf311) so when real users access the URL, they deal with the static page. The problem is that this will essentially loop. So if you are on example.com and let's say all you have is a navigation, if you try to go to "1" you will end up triggering the cloud function which will get you that SSR content, which will then redirect to /1 and so on. What is the best way to break this cycle and essentially only SSR once or for bots, then only serve the static content (or only use static for real users)?

For reference, React Helmet does not work for me since it does not work for seo.

Comment: SEO questions are off-topic here.

Comment: when I say SEO i am basically referring to the page title

Comment: You don't really need Cloud Functions to change titles based on which page/route the user is on, you can simply use `react-helmet`.

Comment: I mentioned at the end that I tried it, but it will not work because link previews will not load with helmet (SSR vs CSR)